# Is there a way to make a Twilio template (content) to allow user choose more than one choice?

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml, twilio-programmable-chat, whatsapi

Can I make list picker template in Twilio but with enabling multiple choosing?

ex.) choose your favorite two colors

- Red
- Black
- Blue
- Green

Now I want the request body to be like:
request.Body = "Red,Green"
or any other format.

I tried to make it using list picker template but it allows only one choice

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid this is, as of now, not possible. The structure of Twilio's [List Picker](https://www.twilio.com/docs/content/twiliolist-picker) is defined by Meta ([Interactive Messages -> List Message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/whatsapp/guides/interactive-messages)) and Twilio only helps you with the needed communication infrastructure to send these messages.

However, you could implement a workaround by asking users for their primary color, and as soon as they respond with "Red", you can send them another list message asking for the secondary color.